Vercel Next.js public folder counts as a serverless function
I'm using Vercel to deploy a simple website with gallery.tsx and gallery/[slug].tsx that display all the images in a certain folder using fs. I do not have any APIs, so I don't know why anything would count as a serverless function. I used create-next-app to make the website.
Warning: Max serverless function size of 250 MB uncompressed reached
Serverless Function's page: gallery.js
Large Dependencies          Uncompressed size
public/images/recent                416.12 MB

All dependencies                    461.18 MB
Serverless Function's page: gallery/[slug].js
Large Dependencies          Uncompressed size
public/images/recent                416.12 MB

I think what is happening is that the images in the public folder are being considered serverless functions and taking up a bunch of space, which exceeds the limit for the hobby plan in Vercel.

Did you add 'use client' on top of your gallery.tsx?

@akos.one No. Was I supposed to?
